# How to upgrade doctrine to 2.6 in symfony

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine, upgrade

I have a task to make app with db where one of the columns has json db data type. I already updated maria db to 10.2 but now I have another problem. Doctrine earlier than 2.6 does not recognize json type and in cmd prompt trow error message

> Unknown database type json requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it

I am not sure what version is in my symfony/vendor. I try to find out but didn't.  Symfony version i 3.3.10. After some reading I understand that I need to update doctrine. How to do that?

Comment: I linked to the question which has extract from Composer doc. If/when you have specific problems with update, ask another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know wich version you are using, look in your `composer.json`. To update it, make a `composer update`to have the last version

Comment: Thanks for fast answer. Can you please be more specific? I should run something like   composer update doctrine  ?

Comment: yes, or if your doctrine version is hard coded, change it in the composer.json first

Comment: did it fix your problem ?

Comment: Yes... and no. :) I really upgraded doctrine/common but the real problem is mysql. I need version 5.7.8 or higher. And I am on it. Thanks for help!!!

Comment: ok, since your question was on doctrine, can you pass it at resolved please ?